# Re-initializing final fields in a static class

Tags: java

I have a static class, like this:

```
public class StaticClass {

    public static final String stringValue;

    static {
        stringValue = OtherClass.someMethod();
    }

}
```

We use `StaticClass.stringValue` all over the place. But in a given situation, I want to force it to reload, so the static initializer runs again.

Is this possible?

I know I could use reflection to set this field manually. But in practice, there are 1000's of fields in this class.

*I'm fully aware of how odd this all sounds, and why I shouldn't do it. I want to know if this is possible. I want the field to be final, so my developers can't accidentally change the values. But I want the fields to all reload after a given user input.*

Comment: That sounds like something other than a static class.

Comment: Move all the code in the `static` block inside a public static method, then in your static block just call this method, and recall it whenever you need it

Comment: I understand why your variables are final, but why are they static?

Comment: Once a value is assigned to a final, it cannot be reassigned. This is what final does.

Comment: @Cruncher We all understand what final does, but if they weren't static he could simply create a new instance. In other words, a brand new set of final variables.

Comment: It sounds like you need to trust your developers more. This is why we have things like code review and unit tests.

Comment: Why would you need to *reinitialize* your fields if they are already `final`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `so my developers can't accidentally change the values. But I want the fields to all reload after a given user input.` And therein lies the root of my comment

Comment: @Cruncher if my *technical leader* doesn't understand the problem in his/her design, I won't trust him/her either...

Comment: Heh. As I said, I'm fully aware of this not being a 'sensible' design, but thanks for reading my note at the bottom there Luiggi.

Comment: make all the members private, and just expose public getter methods for each member plus one public 'reload all' method ?

Comment: For the record, this class is used for localization. Each field is a key, the value is the localized String. The class is automatically generated (by us), and the whole purpose of doing it this way is for developer convenience. We have a mammoth project, and it's nice just to use `Strings.key` and it just works. Originally, changing language at runtime was never an option, but now it is.

I know I could change it to methods. I know I could make it non-final. But that's not what I'm asking. I'd prefer if people would contribute solutions (or a "No"), rather than criticize the design.

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths then he should be worried about the developers using the public 'reload all' method! :D

Comment: Ok, here's another idea: Have a `private static Map<String, Foo> finalFieldsWannabes` where you will store the name and values of your supposed final fields which will be filled in a `static` method, then create a `public static` method to access to the values of this map on top of `finalFieldsWannabes.get`, and you could reload the map as many times you wish...

Comment: Sticky, why is it less convenient to write `MyClass.getKey()` than `MyClass.key`? None of us are trying to criticize your design (and in fact, most of us are here to help you), but we can't really offer the best solution OR tell you no until we understand what it is you are trying to do. So keep answering our questions until we reach a conclusion, or just throw your hands up in the air and give up.

Comment: @Sticky "One trap that many posters fall into is to ask how to achieve some "small" aim, but never say what the larger aim is. Often the smaller aim is either impossible or rarely a good idea - instead, a different approach is needed. Again, if you provide more context when writing your problem statement, we can suggest better designs. It's fine to specify how you're currently trying to solve your bigger problem, of course - that's likely to be necessary detail - but include the bigger goal too." -Jon Skeet https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @Cruncher; noted. @John; It barely is, it's simply that if there was a quick solution here, it'd save me changing our class generator, and changing the thousands of 'Strings.key' to 'Strings.getKey()'. It sounds like consensus is that what I suggested is possible, but might get weird. So I'll likely just go with stripping the `final` out.

Answer (score 1):

A [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) will only run static initializers once per class (as the class is loaded into memory).

If you want to keep the static string as `final`, the only way I can see of doing this is by using a custom classloader (or maybe some byte code magic via [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)).

If you discard the classloader and load the class again with a new classloader, the static block will run again.

Note, this may cause problems since the old class will not be equal to the new class. All objects referencing the static final field(s) will also need to be reloaded.

This sounds messy and hacky and smells of bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the initialisation code into a method, which is called in the static initialiser block and also exposed to be called again later.

For completeness : it is possible to force a class to be re-loaded and hence re-initialized, by using the ClassLoader - for example this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html).  While technically possible, it is very unlikely that this is a good solution to your problem.

Comment: His field is final actually.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to maintain a relationship that `stringValue` cannot be something other than `OtherClass.someMethod()` why not just use a getter method that fetches it, in place of even maintaining a variable?

Something of the likes:

```
public class StaticClass {
    public static getStringValue()
    {
        return OtherClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I think we need more information into the problem. There is likely a much better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution = remove final word before stringValue declaration and do that.

```
public static void staticValueInitialisation() {
            stringValue = OtherClass.someMethod();
        }
```

Comment: The field is `final` so how could your solution deal with that?

Comment: Hmm... it wasn't when I was reading your question. Now if it is final I cant be changed or reinitialized because of final. Only internal state of the object can be changed, but we know String class is a final class so there is no possibility to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Java has access modifiers for this sort of thing. It looks like a situation where you want developers to be able to access the value without changing it, which is what a public (static) getter would be for. You could make the field private but not final, and have other code that reloaded or did any other kind of modification you wanted.